# How exactly is "participation" computed here on Meta?

Tags: support, users

As you can see, on [this page](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users), users are ranked according to their participation. So, some users are ranked higher than others as they have participated more in comparison.

My question is how exactly is this participation calculated?

Suppose, a user A and a user B, both logs in once per day for a period of 7 days.

Suppose, user A, in those 7 days, posts 3 comments, cast 2 votes and does no other actions. And also suppose, that user B casts 2 votes and posts one question and one answer and does no other actions.

So, in that given period, which user (A or B) is to be considered as having participated more?

Comment: From main meta [How is meta participation calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/182734)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tool tip says everything. Hover on the tab "[participation](/users)". The text is displayed as.

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

Add all these from last 60 days.

[image: Gif of participation tab]

Comment: Oh so simply the sum n1+n2+ .... is the formula. I thought it's a bit more complex than that.

Comment: @Rickross Yes, it's a simple formula. SE uses easy ones for things we think complex and vice versa

Comment: Also, if could indicate if the Participation Value is computed as an integer sum of |posts|+|votes|+|comments|+|edits|, or if the various |n|s are weighted differently etc, and how often & when the value is computed, could be helpful. Thank you :)